# PDO/PHP : Fetch Array and Prepared Statements

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement, fetch

As you can see I'm trying to fetch rows from table while using prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, 10");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $row_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo $row['title'];
echo $row['name'];
}
```

It doesn't echo anything.

Edit: var_dump is showing this log :

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''0', 10' at line 1" }

**Edit 2**: Here is how I declare my `$row_start`

```
$row_start = "0";
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != "0" )
{
$row_start = $_GET['page'];
if ($row_start == "1") {
$row_start = "0";
}else{
$row_start = ($row_start-1) * 10;
}                       
}
```

Comment: Does your SQL work when you run it straight in the database?

Comment: @andrewsi Yes! if I replace `?` with a number and run it, it does work.

Comment: Try binding your parameter explicitly as an integer `$stmt->bindParam(1, $row_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @andrewsi no luck. I have the same code in old mysql ext and it's working, but not sure why it fails after converting it to PDO

Comment: Is there anything returned by the database? Does `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo())` print anything?

Comment: @andrewsi: Edited post, check the log.

Comment: All I can suggest then is that you try explicitly casting `$row_start` to an int, too: `(int)$row_start` - that error message looks like it's still being treated as a string for some reason.

Comment: Your param is still being passed as a String, see the ending `'` after 0.

Comment: @andrewsi using `(int)` gives me fatal error. also, I added detail on how the variable is given value.

Comment: You need to declare it without the quotes - those are turning it into a string.

Comment: @andrewsi Even if I do that, doesn't `$_GET['page']` gives the variable a string value too ?

Comment: I _think_ if you initialise it as an int, it will try to treat it as an int when you assign values to it. I get a little hazy when it comes to the internal workings of PHP, alas.

Comment: @xperator - oh, and I made a mistake with the casting code, too - it should be `(int) $row_start` with a space.

Comment: Confirmed the above. What's the point of telling PDO how to treat the parameter if it needs to be init/typecasted to the specific type? If you tell PDO it is a `PDO::PARAM_INT`, it should automatically be treated as an int. Answer below has the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the value type will be string.

You can set it to an integer like this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $row_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**Update:**

Even though you are forcing it to INT, it's still passing it as a string.

Look at your error message:

```
near ''0', 10' at line 1" }
```

And specifically the ending `'` after 0, indicating it is a string.

```
0'
```

**Update**

Manually typecasting the variable is needed, even if you pass the expected PDO type:

```
$limit = (int) 1;
$limit2 = (int) 1;


$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT :limit, :offset");
$stmt->bindParam(":limit", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":offset", $limit2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Yes I think it's because I am giving that variable string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?");
$stmt->execute(array(10));
```

Comment: @wanovak is passing the value directly to the statement via execute, not through binding. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php